# Why is PropertiesProvider missing from gax?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

When I try to do `StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()`. I see this failure:

```
2018-11-07 20:13:58 [http-nio-8442-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log(182) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/gax/core/PropertiesProvider] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.core.PropertiesProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getVersionProperty(ServiceOptions.java:647)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getLibraryVersion(ServiceOptions.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions.getHttpRequestInitializer(HttpTransportOptions.java:152)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.<init>(HttpStorageRpc.java:90)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:472)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.getStorageRpcV1(StorageOptions.java:121)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.<init>(StorageImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:37)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:459)
```

I've included gax-grpc dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.34.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Searching for this error online say it is possible if there are multiple gax version in dependency:tree, I have verified that there is only one version of gax.

I don't understand why this is failing, does someone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This issue got resolved when we updated our `google-cloud-storage` version from 1.10.0 to 1.51.0